# ORA-01722: invalid number only on select * from view, not against view directly

Tags: oracle, ora-01722

I'm getting ORA-01722: invalid number but only when I `select * from theView` but not when I select against the theView directly (using the SQL inside the view's `CREATE OR REPLACE...`).

*(I have faced and understand this error before, as well as running aggregates against NULL values, that one shouldn't store VARCHARS in NUMBER columns, etc. but am struggling to understand this issue)*

Comment: Do the view and the table have the same column data types? Was the table altered recently?

Comment: Table wasn't altered but only certain queries cause the issue (including the case I'm using to debug now).
No, the sql is kind of a mess (two UNION ALLs, and lots of casts (to_number(to_char(RSQR,'9.99EEEE')) AS RSQR)...

Answer (score 3):

Usually you get it when oracle executes your filter predicate that should filter only numbers, after predicates where you use it as a number.

Simple example:

```sql
create table t as
     select '1' x, 'num' xtype from dual union all
     select 'A' x, 'str' xtype from dual
/
create index t_ind on t(x);
```

You can see we get ORA-01722 in this very simple example even though we specified filter `xtype='num'` before `x > 0`:

```
select x
from (
     select x
     from t
     where xtype='num'
     ) v
where v.x > 0;

ERROR:
ORA-01722: invalid number
```

Execution plan:

```sql
Plan hash value: 1601196873

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name | E-Rows |E-Bytes| Cost (%CPU)| E-Time   |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |      |        |       |     3 (100)|          |
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| T    |      1 |     6 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

Query Block Name / Object Alias (identified by operation id):
-------------------------------------------------------------

   1 - SEL$F5BB74E1 / T@SEL$2

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter((TO_NUMBER("X")>0 AND "XTYPE"='num'))
```

As you can see from the plan, inline view was `merged` and both predicates are on the same level.

Now compare with this:

```sql
select/*+ 
           no_merge(v) 
           opt_param('_optimizer_filter_pushdown' 'false')
     */ 
      x
from (
     select x
     from t
     where xtype='num'
     ) v
where v.x > 0;

X
-
1
```

Execution plan:

```sql
Plan hash value: 3578092569

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name | E-Rows |E-Bytes| Cost (%CPU)| E-Time   |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |      |        |       |     3 (100)|          |
|*  1 |  VIEW              |      |      1 |     3 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| T    |      1 |     6 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------

Query Block Name / Object Alias (identified by operation id):
-------------------------------------------------------------

   1 - SEL$2 / V@SEL$1
   2 - SEL$2 / T@SEL$2

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter(TO_NUMBER("V"."X")>0)
   2 - filter("XTYPE"='num')
```

Read more about this: http://orasql.org/2013/06/10/too-many-function-executions/

Comment: Interesting. Thanks. I'll try to update the column orders (and maybe union clause order).